# Relationship between conductivity and electrostatic screening

Tags: electrostatics, debye-length

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of [electric field screening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric-field_screening). Namely I'm trying to reconcile this property of a fluid with the bulk property of conductivity.

I can understand how a fluid of free ions would screen the electrostatic field of a charge. And I understand one can calculate the [Debye length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_length) of a neutral, ionic fluid such as seawater based on ionic concentrations. To me, the utility of this model is in the bottom-up approach; one can find the screening length as a function of known ionic concentrations.

But is there a bulk material version of this model? For example, if I had an oscillating dipole under the ocean, there are models that account for the EM fields given off by an oscillating dipole in a media with $\epsilon, \mu, \sigma$. But in the electrostatic case, a textbook would say the fields inside the conductor of sea water go to zero.

This is confusing to me because both the Debye length and the conductivity of an ionic solution are dependent on ion concentration. Is there a way to relate Debye length and conductivity? Does this have to do with appropriate time/length scales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually relate the Debye length to a charge/ion density rather directly through the Drude model.

In the simplest case you have $\lambda_D \sim \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$, where $n$ is the density. Using the density you can calculate the plasma frequency, $\omega_p \sim \sqrt{n}$. For a simple drude model the DC conductivity is related to the charge density through $\sigma \sim \omega_p^2\sim$ so $\sigma \sim \frac{1}{\lambda_D^2}$.

The main assumption here is that the charge density is uniform, has a single characteristic charge relaxation time. Of course, there are additional temperature contributions that can go into the Debye length and not conductivity, so some care is needed in these relations when you need explicit numbers.